# Properly setting userid value with current code

Tags: php, cookies

I've been attempting to make this work for a few days and I'm out of ideas.

I'm using third party software and I'm trying to integrate another program which requires the USERID to identify the user logged in on the other application.

The code below is the login script, I've tried setting userid in the cookies but it's not properly selecting the id related to the username. The main program does not use PHP sessions, only cookies.

I would be much appreciated if you could assist me with properly setting this up.

Also, the structure for the Users DB table is straight forward: `userid, username, password`

```
include_once("deps.php");

function pv($value) {
    $value2 = trim($value);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        return addslashes($value2);
    } else {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($value2);
    }
}


function pcrtlang($string) {
    require("deps.php");

    $rs_connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass) or die("Couldn't connect the db");
    $rs_select_db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $rs_connect) or die("Couldn't select the db in pcrtlang");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $safestring = pv($string);
    $findbasestring = "SELECT * FROM languages WHERE basestring LIKE BINARY '$safestring'";
    $findbasestringq = @mysql_query($findbasestring, $rs_connect);

    if(mysql_num_rows($findbasestringq) == 0) {
        $addstring = "INSERT INTO languages (language,languagestring,basestring) VALUES ('en-us','$safestring','$safestring')";
        @mysql_query($addstring, $rs_connect);
    }

    $findstring = "SELECT languagestring FROM languages WHERE basestring LIKE BINARY '$safestring' AND language = '$mypcrtlanguage'";

    $findstringq = @mysql_query($findstring, $rs_connect);
    if(mysql_num_rows($findstringq) == 0) {
        return "$string";
    } else {
        $rs_result_qs = mysql_fetch_object($findstringq);

        return "$rs_result_qs->languagestring";
    }
}


if (array_key_exists("RURI", $_REQUEST)) {
    $ruri = $_REQUEST['RURI'];
} else {
    $ruri = "../repair";
}

if (array_key_exists("METHOD", $_REQUEST)) {
    $method = $_REQUEST['METHOD'];
} else {
    $method = "";
}


if(isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $userid =$_POST["userid"];
    $validated = false;

    #check code here

    require("deps.php");
    $rs_connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass) or die("Couldn't connect the db");
    $rs_select_db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $rs_connect) or die("Couldn't select the db");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
        date_default_timezone_set("$pcrt_timezone");
    }
    $currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    #Set time here for how many minutes before login attempts are expired.
    $loginattempts_expiretime_minutes = 60; 

    $lesshourstamp = (strtotime($currentdatetime) - (60 * $loginattempts_expiretime_minutes));

    $lesshour = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lesshourstamp);

    $rs_clear_ip = "DELETE FROM loginattempts WHERE attempttime < '$lesshour'";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($rs_clear_ip, $rs_connect);

    $rs_find_ip = "SELECT * FROM loginattempts WHERE ipaddress = '$ipaddress' AND username = '$user'";
    $rsfind_result = mysql_query($rs_find_ip, $rs_connect);


    if(isset($passwords[$user])) if($passwords[$user]==$pass) $validated = true;

    if(!$validated) {
        require("deps.php");
        $rs_connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass) or die("Couldn't connect the db");
        $rs_select_db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $rs_connect) or die("Couldn't select the db");
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
            date_default_timezone_set("$pcrt_timezone");
        }
        $currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $rs_insert_ip = "INSERT INTO loginattempts (username,ipaddress,attempttime) VALUES ('$user','$ipaddress','$currentdatetime');";
        $rs_result = mysql_query($rs_insert_ip, $rs_connect);
    }

    $userloginattempts = mysql_num_rows($rsfind_result);

    #Set max login attempts here
    $maxloginattempts = 4;

    if($userloginattempts > $maxloginattempts) {
        $validated = false;
        $exceededattempts = 1;
    }


    if($validated) {
        if(isset($cookiedomain)) {
            setcookie("username", $user, time()+36000, "/","$cookiedomain");
            setcookie("password", $pass, time()+36000, "/","$cookiedomain"); 
        } else {
            setcookie("username", $user, time()+36000, "/");
            setcookie("password", $pass, time()+36000, "/");
        }

        if("$method" == "POST") {

            if (preg_match("/store/i", $ruri)) {
                $gotouri = urlencode("../store");
                header("Location: loglogin.php?gotouri=$gotouri");
            } else {
                $gotouri = urlencode("../repair");
                header("Location: loglogin.php?gotouri=$gotouri");
            }
        } else {
            $gotouri = urlencode($ruri);
            header("Location: loglogin.php?gotouri=$gotouri");
        }

    } else {
        $failedlogin = "1"; 
    }
//End login code
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    if(!isset($pcrt_stylesheet)) {
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../repair/style.css\">";
    } else {
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../repair/$pcrt_stylesheet\">";
    }
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../repair/fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ani.css">
    <title><?php echo pcrtlang("Login"); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script>
    <!--
    function sf(){document.loginbox.username.focus();}
    // -->
    </script>


</head>
<body onLoad=sf()>
    <center><br><br><img src="<?php echo "$logo"; ?>" class="animated bounceIn">
    <br><br><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form name="loginbox" action="login.php" method="post">
                <font class=text12b><?php echo pcrtlang("Username"); ?>:</font>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="textbox">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <font class=text12b><?php echo pcrtlang("Password"); ?>:</font>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="textbox">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2 style="text-align:center;">
             <input type="hidden" name="RURI" value="<?php echo "$ruri"; ?>">
             <input type="hidden" name="METHOD" value="<?php echo "$method"; ?>"><br>
             <input type="submit" value="<?php echo pcrtlang("Login"); ?>" class="button">
             </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php

    if (isset($failedlogin)) {
        if (isset($exceededattempts)) {
            echo "<br><br><div class=notify style=\"width:250px\"><font class=textred12>".pcrtlang("Sorry, max login attempts exceeded").".</font></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<br><br><div class=notify style=\"width:250px\"><font class=textred12>".pcrtlang("Sorry, Invalid username/password combination").".</font></div>";
        }
    }

    ?>
    </center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, After spending some time thinking about it. It ended up being very simple.
I created one line of code that fixed the issue.

```
$id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = '$user' LIMIT 1"),0);
```